An error occurred when building Vector store with Langchain
I am trying to work with the Chroma vector database from langchain but I get -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
    loader = UnstructuredMarkdownLoader("./test.md")
    docs = loader.load()
    text_spliter = ChineseTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200, add_start_index=True)
    splits = text_spliter.split_documents(docs)
    embedding_func = XinferenceEmbeddings(
        server_url="http://127.0.0.1:9997",
        model_uid="bge-large-zh-v1.5"
    )
    vector_store = Chroma.from_documents(splits, embedding_func)

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Please tell me how to solve this problem.
